# Native crash at libc.so on Anroid 12

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, arm

I recently updated my app to android 12.
An error show up only on this android version, this is the Stack trace:

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.example.name <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000005136c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+180)
  #00  pc 00000000000200f8  /data/app/~~VttD3Qdhj5r5DYPnaVPFsw==/com.example.name-FTS4HH_ehO_EiX6MUqQmHw==/lib/arm64/libmonodroid.so (xamarin::android::internal::MonodroidRuntime::mono_log_handler(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, void*)+144)
  #00  pc 000000000028b6f8  /data/app/~~VttD3Qdhj5r5DYPnaVPFsw==/com.example.name-FTS4HH_ehO_EiX6MUqQmHw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (monoeg_g_logv_nofree+192)
```

Any help?

Comment: for android 12 migration you need to make several changes in your codebase, i also did migration to 12 recently check this here with solution :  https://medium.com/native-mobile-bits/lets-use-android-12-migration-of-our-android-apps-to-android12-api-31-af329b6829d0

Comment: Is there any error message? Had you checked the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/12/12.0) about the Android12?

Comment: I tested the app on android 12 emulator, it chrashes on startup with no error messages, but i got this output :                                                                                                               [libc] Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 9335 (Finalizer), pid 9307 (roidoma.name)
Could not connect to the debugger.

Comment: `Could not connect to the debugger.` seems a common issue, you can try to disable the Fast Deployment.